# Count only if field is filled and same as other field value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about an sql query i want to make. Supose i have an column with the follow values in table: school with column: grades.

```
 SUI grades | Score
  2  9          2
  2  9          
  5  4          1
  5  4          1
  5  4
  6  1          1
  6  1
```

And Table Grade_scores

```
id      score_1   score_2
 1         4         1
```

Now i wan't an output where it groups the SUI that counts grades **only** if **Score is filled** and **school.grades** is **same** as **Grade_scores.score_1** OR **Grade_scores.score_2** . So my output will be:

```
SUI Count 
 5    2
 6    1
```

The code so far...

```sql
SELECT SUI, Count(Grades)
FROM mytable
WHERE Score <> ''
GROUP BY SUI
```

Comment: Can you post whaat you have done so far?

Comment: SELECT SUI, Count(Grades)
FROM mytable 
WHERE Score <> ''
GROUP BY SUI

But now i have to make an join query that looks if school.grades = Grade_scores. score_1 OR Grade_scores.score_2

Comment: Seriously consider amending your schema. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

(untested):

```
SELECT SUI, count(GRADES) As Count 
FROM school
INNER JOIN Gradescores ON s.grades = score_1 OR s.grades = score_2 
WHERE Score>'' AND NOT Score IS NULL
GROUP BY SUI
```

Comment: My answer is basically what @the_boy_za asked, but in a different language, when he said "Now i wan't an output where it groups the SUI that counts grades only if Score is filled and school.grades is same as Grade_scores.score_1 OR Grade_scores.score_2", does it really need more comment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` your `school` and `grade_scores` tables on `grades` being IN the two values in `grade_scores`:

```
SELECT s.SUI, COUNT(s.grades) AS `Count`
FROM grade_scores gs
JOIN school s ON s.Score IS NOT NULL AND s.grades IN (gs.score_1, gs.score_2)
GROUP BY s.SUI
```

Output:

```
SUI Count
5   2
6   1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9nDF9BWcXU2KBwC5Bq2amp/0)

**Note** This query assumes the empty values in the `Score` column are `NULL`. If they are an empty string, replace `s.Score IS NOT NULL` with `s.Score != ''`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do this using `exists`, because a `join` approach would double count if there are duplicate values in `score_1`/`score_2`:

```
select s.sui, count(*)
from scores s
where s.score is not null and
      s.score in (select 1
                  from grade_scores gs
                  where s.grades in (gs.score_1, gs.score_2)
                 )
group by s.sui;
```